# SP2010 Surveys and IE - Document mode

Tags: 2010, internet-explorer, browser-compatibility, survey

For everything else in SP we have been using IE8 Document compatibility mode and it went along just fine.
Recently a site collection owner created a survey, only to find out that clicking "Respond to this survey" blinks a gray layer over the page once, bringing him back to the same place without showing the questions.
After researching found that it worked fine on Chrome, as well as when document compatibility mode was set to IE9 in IE debugger tools.

I must keep everything else in IE8 mode, so is there a way to set the "X-UA-Compatible" meta tag to IE9 only for surveys?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got an answer on another forum:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/4138fcd0-614a-46a4-aa7e-00fcb0ab7107/sp2010-surveys-and-ie-document-mode?prof=required

> set the surveys page to IE 9 Document mode in SharePoint Designer as
>   following.
>
> > 1. Open the SharePoint Designer with the site.
> > 2. Click the Master Pages, copy the v4.master page, and rename the copied page with v4_1.master.
> > 3. Click the v4.master page, then click the Edit file.
> > 4. Replace the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>` with `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>`
> > 5. Then click the Lists and Libraries, click the survey page.
> > 6. Edit the overview.aspx page, change the MasterPageFile with the v4_1.master as following
> >        MasterPageFile="../../_catalogs/masterpage/v4_1.master